# Does the quality filter apply to answers?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, quality-filter

I just [tested the post quality filter in the answer area](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/127072/1), and entering nonsense text like "qwerty" repeatedly did not trip the filter.  Why?

Comment: I know they have a quality score, whether or not they're auto-rejected I don't know

Comment: Did verify that _"qwerty"_ isn't a real word? **:)**

Comment: Such questions will probably get an automatic VLQ flag, but they are not rejected, as far as I know. Maybe some of them should be rejected.

Comment: Another option - quality filter applied only on users with low reputation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on what I see in the flag queue, answers do not have a low-quality filter.  Or, if they do, the bar is very low.

It is much easier for mods to dispose of bad answers than bad questions, and users who post too many bad answers can be answer-banned.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you get a message like "The answer you posted is too short" when you post a very short answer.

Comment: I am not sure of the exact words, so pleas edit, if you may.

Comment: That is true; there is a minimum character limit. Additional quality filters are imposed on questions.

Comment: I don't believe you @Robert, There's a 10 character answer from 2012 [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65273/shortest-posts). Unless over a certain rep the limit doesn't apply? Notice the repeated names :-).

Comment: @Ben: If you edit one of those answers, you'll see why they have so few characters in them. :)

Comment: The current minimum is 30 characters here on Meta.